# Titan Graph Database with Cassandra

Tags: database, graph, cassandra, titan

Is it possible to install the titan graph Database which uses cassandra as the backend in windows 7? I tried installing the titan-server-0.4.4 which had cassandra in it. This downloaded zip had titan.sh, but as i'm using windows i require the titan.bat file. The command that i was to run is "titan.sh -c cassandra-es start"

Comment: Latest version is 1.0 and you should be using that. http://titandb.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run on Windows, you can try installing Cassandra and Elasticsearch separately because the Titan 1.0 distribution does not include a `titan.bat`. In addition, there were some fixes that have been put into Titan post-1.0 release that will help with running on Windows.

First, you can use the DataStax Cassandra distribution for Windows from [Planet Cassandra](http://www.planetcassandra.org/archived-versions-of-datastaxs-distribution-of-apache-cassandra/). Based on Titan's [version compatibility matrix](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/version-compat.html), you should go with the MSI installer for Cassandra 2.1.x. For Elasticsearch, you should go with [version 1.5.2](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-5-2) ([installation reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/_installation.html)).

Next, you should unzip [`titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip`](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip). Then you will need to copy this [`gremlin.bat`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/7eee854ee0390e471ac43791f6515a449c53c9b8/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/bin/gremlin.bat) and [`gremlin-server.bat`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/7eee854ee0390e471ac43791f6515a449c53c9b8/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/bin/gremlin-server.bat) into the `%TITAN_HOME%\bin` directory. You also will need to copy this [`gremlin-server.yaml`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/89c0a2b30e798a13e098949c219730b228bcc82a/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml) and [`titan-cassandra-es-server.properties`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/89c0a2b30e798a13e098949c219730b228bcc82a/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/titan-cassandra-es-server.properties) into the `%TITAN_HOME%\conf\gremlin-server` directory.

Now, you should be ready to test it out. Start Cassandra and Elasticsearch first. Then start Titan Server with `%TITAN_HOME%\bin\gremlin-server.bat`.